# Codeigniter session won't work

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I've been watching this tuts from yt how to build login system with Codeigniter

[Here is link from tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wpUqyTRxbds&list=PL161C7E0E6A01B1E0&index=7)

when guy from video put this code to get user data

```
<?php print_r ($this->session->all_userdata ());?>
```

he gets array with all data like in this video.
I receive array like this

```
Array( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1467913653)
```

So when try to login it always redirect me to restricted area even when email and password are good, and all should work.

Is it problem because I use Codeigniter 3, in video is CI 2?

Comment: probably.according to documentation:This method is DEPRECATED. Use `userdata()` with no parameters instead.read https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#CI_Session::all_userdata.

Comment: so it should be `<?php print_r ($this->session->userdata());?>`

Comment: Can you add your session config information to your question?

Comment: It probably isn't a Codeigniter version problem. While there are some deprecated functions used they are all still valid for use in the current version (3.0.6). Make very sure you have followed the tutorial _exactly_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make sure that session library is loaded you can auto load it from config/autoload.php as follows

```
$config['libraries'] = array('session');
```

or load it in controller constructor as follows

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

and then you can get session data by call this method

```
$this->session->userdata();
```

I hope my answer would be useful

Comment: Yes, library sessions are on autoload.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve all of the existing userdata, you can simply omit the item key (magic getter only works for properties):

```
$_SESSION
```

// or:

```
$this->session->userdata();
```

[Here](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#retrieving-session-data) is the documentation